# How to properly use Typescript interface on ImmutableJS Record classes?

Tags: javascript, typescript, immutable.js

I've tried searching on how to do this properly yet I haven't come up with satisfying solution. I know Immutable records are factories. My code looks like this:

```
import { Record } from 'immutable'

interface ISessionDefaults {
  id: number | null,
  email: string,
}

interface ISession {
  id: number,
  email: string,
}

const defaults: ISessionDefaults = {
  id: null,
  email: '',
}

class Session extends Record(defaults) implements ISession {
}
```

I'm getting type error on class definition:

```
[tsserver 2420] [E] Class 'Session' incorrectly implements interface 'ISession'.
  Type 'Session' is missing the following properties from type 'ISession': id, email
```

Which is understandable, so I expand the class definition like this:

```
class Session extends Record(defaults) implements ISession {
  id: number
  email: string
}
```

At this point I get another type error: `[tsserver 2564] [E] Property 'id' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.`

OK so time to set defaults. I change class definition:

```
class Session extends Record(defaults) implements ISession {
  id: number = 0
  email: string = ''
}
```

But this actually fails to compile since I'm setting it directly. The error is `Error: Cannot set on an immutable record.`

I guess I can define `constructor` method but that means calling `super` after I set the initial values which isn't valid either.